# JMeter - fail a test based on the average response time

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

I am running a JMeter job in Jenkins using performance plugin. I need to fail a job if the average response time < 3 seconds. I see the "duration assertion" in jmeter, but that works on each thread (each http request). Instead is it possible to do the duration assertion on average for each page?

This is the way I tried adding the BeanSehll Listener and Assertion.

```
Recording Controller
       **Home Page**
         BeanShell Listener
         Debug Sampler
       **Page1**
         BeanShell Listener
         Debug Sampler
Beanshell Assertion
View Results Tree
```

Answer (score 3):

You can implement this check via some form of [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) scripting

1. Add a [Beanshell Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener) at the same level as all your requests live
2. Put the following code into Beanshell Listener's "Script" area

   ```
   String requests = vars.get("requests");
   String times = vars.get("times");
   long requestsSum = 0;
   long timesSum = 0;

   if (requests != null && times != null) {
       log.info("requests: " + requests);
       requestsSum = Long.parseLong(vars.get("requests"));
       timesSum = Long.parseLong(vars.get("times"));
   }

   long thisRequest = sampleResult.getTime();
   timesSum += thisRequest;
   requestsSum++;

   vars.put("requests", String.valueOf(requestsSum));
   vars.put("times", String.valueOf(timesSum));


   long average = timesSum / requestsSum;

   if (average > 3000){
       sampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
       sampleResult.setResponseMessage("Average response time is greater than threshold");
   }
   ```

   The code above will record sums of response times for each request and total number of requests into `times` and `requests` [JMeter Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for comprehensive information on Beanshell scripting in Apache JMeter.

Comment: I get errors like: ERROR - jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``long times = Long.parseLong(vars.get("times")); long requests = Long.parseLong(v . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Long.parseLong 
 WARN  - jmeter.assertions.BeanShellAssertion: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``long times = Long.parseLong(vars.get("times")); long requests = Long.parseLong(v . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Method Invocation Long.parseLong

Comment: It looks like that `times` and/or `requests` variables aren't visible or cannot be cast to long. Is your Assertion in the same thread group? Any chance it may be executed before Listener? What are values of "times" and "requests" variables i.e. in Debug Sampler?

Comment: yes..times/requests are not visible in Jmeter variables/response data. How do I populate them then? The Listner and assertion are in the same level as you suggested. Appreciate your help here.

Comment: Can you show screenshot of your test plan so I could take a look into location of the Beanshell Listener and Assertion and try to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Apologies for confusion, it looks like that Assertion is executed earlier than listener, I've modified my answer and now average response time calculation and failure logic lives in the listener.

Comment: This code works more like "Duration Assertion" asserting each request based on the response time. The "timesSum" and "requestsSum" are getting reset for each request. There should be a way to save the values between each request. Is it "vars.put"?

Comment: Yep, average response times and requests numbers are stored as JMeter Variables `requests` and `times` correspondingly. Each request they are being read, incremented and stored back followed by check if the average response time is matches expectations

Comment: I think vars.put does not work.."requests" and "times" gets reset to null for each HTTP request. I tried printing them out. When I tried for 1 page(Home page) and a Debug sampler, i see there are 2 Home pages and 4 debug samplers in the report (I ran it for Number of users: 2, Loopcount:1). I am all confused :-(

Answer (score 0):

Based on the other answer, I managed to create something that works while using multiple threads.

Add the following code as a script to your JSR223 listener, you can also save it to file and load it from file (for easy reuse). I used a parameter in seconds to set the duration threshold.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;

int totalRequests = Integer.parseInt(ctx.getThreadGroup().getSamplerController().getProperty("LoopController.loops").getStringValue()) * ctx.getThreadGroup().getNumThreads();
long requestsCount = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("requestsCount"+sampleResult.toString(),0);
long timesSum = JMeterUtils.getPropDefault("times"+sampleResult.toString(),0);

long thisRequestTime = sampleResult.getTime();
timesSum += thisRequestTime;
requestsCount++;

JMeterUtils.setProperty("requestsCount"+sampleResult.toString(), String.valueOf(requestsCount));
JMeterUtils.setProperty("times"+sampleResult.toString(), String.valueOf(timesSum));

long average = timesSum / requestsCount;

long threshold = Integer.parseInt(args[0])*1000;
if (requestsCount >= totalRequests) {
    if(average > threshold){
        sampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
        sampleResult.setResponseMessage("Average response time is greater than threshold, average: " + String.valueOf(average) + ", threshold: " + threshold);
    }
    log.info("Average response time (" + sampleResult.toString() + "): " + String.valueOf(average) + ", threshold: " + threshold);
}
```

This stores it in the global properties, that are saved for the full JVM run. To keep consistency in between runs, I added a setup thread group with a JSR223 sampler, with this code:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
JMeterUtils.getJMeterProperties().clear();
log.info("cleared properties");
```