# JMeter handle "test-completed" event

Tags: jmeter

I calculate some statistics (e.g. average request duration) while my tests are running using code similar to this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27446405/2173353

However, I want to know when the test is done running (all the samplers have executed), so that I act upon the statistics then, and not before that. Essentially, I want to assert on the average duration of the requests when all requests are done.

Is there a way to execute code when the test is about to finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must probably be looking for the [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group). It is some form of "special" thread group, the difference from "normal" [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) is that the tearDown Thread Group is being executed **after** all other Thread Groups therefore you will be able to perform your "near the end" actions there.

More information: [How to Use the SetUp Thread Group in JMeter When Preparing a Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-setup-thread-group-jmeter-when-preparing-load-test)

Comment: Thanks. The only problem is that it looks like that you cannot access the variables of another thread group from that tearDown thread group, so I will probably try to use properties instead. Or maybe try to find something similar to BeanShell's `bsh.shared` for Groovy. Any extra hints are welcome. :)

Comment: `props.put('key', value)` should do the trick for you. See [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) article for more details if needed